# How do I prevent child objects from stretching when duplicated on the parent's faces?

Tags: parent, dupli-groups

I have run into an issue where I'm building a shield in blender. I created a duplicate object of the faces on the shield I want rivets to be placed on and then made that object a parent of my rivet object. When I duplicated the rivet object on the faces of the parent, all of the duplicates are stretched along the Z-axis. How do I prevent this from happening, or what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Screenshot: https://drive.google.com/open?id=13_zHFm6PFo8dwgb5qH93gDyfJvApIaax
Blender file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=11scI0oYaUpaq9c0Lk2Tc5ysop4HlSxVE

Thank you

Comment: Hi. Please add any images useing the built-in uploader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your Rivet_Surface and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> to apply the scale. You have changed the scale of your object on its Z axis in *Object* mode and now you must make this scale real.